# Convert Long BSON to Date

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp, bson

I am working on this TCP Proxy project written in NodeJs & Typescript , and I got a response from a TCP server, the data from the server is written in BSON format.

this is the deserialized BSON data from the server. I am trying to convert that Long value that I believe is something related with date or time, I have tried to convert the number into int32 mongodb but it didn't work.

[image]

so I want those number to be somehow readable date format using NodeJs.

I used `js-bson` library for this.
I also don't have any access on the database backend source code

Been stuck here for like hours already.
thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you know which date/time (~ish) to expect, `new Date(Number(BSON.Long('637896884636858022').toBigInt() / 1000000n))` yields a date in 1990 which I doubt is correct.

Comment: I think those numbers represent the current date or time of the server. Because that packet is sent to synchronize the server's time with the clients

Comment: Any clue where the data is coming from? What platform is generating the BSON data? It doesn't look like a regular Unix timestamp.